# Windows 8 randomly powers up pc?

Tags: windows-8, power-management, asus-laptop, zenbook

I have installed Windows 8 PRO on my Asus UX31E (Zenbook) and sometimes happens that after I leave it charging after powering it off, I found it powered up (actually I found it in sleep mode because lid is closed).
I thought that I forgot to power it off but I'm now pretty sure that wasn't my mistake after it happened already 5 or 6 times.

Is it a known bug or may be some setting that leads to that behavior? 
Ofc this wasn't happening on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have "Allow wake timers" enabled in the Windows power settings, which allows Windows to wake up your computer in order to install updates and perform other maintenance. To disable it:

1. Type "power options" in the Start screen and select "Settings" from the right side of the screen
2. Select "Power options"
3. Click "Change plan settings" next to your currently selected power plan
4. Click "Advanced power settings"
5. Go to Sleep > Allow wake timers and disable "On battery" and "Plugged in"